# Como descobrir a porta da JVM em linux?

Tags: java, linux

Tenho servidor linux rodando uma JRE 1.7 e preciso usar o VisualVM para monitorar o desempenho das aplicações rodando na mesma.

O VisualVM usa JMX para conectar no host linux porem ele espera algo como

```
<hostname>:<port>
```

A principio achei que fosse a porta ssh 22, porém pesquisando li que se trata da porta da JVM no servidor.

Como descubro a porta que a JVM esta rodando?

Comment: Em ambiente Windows é utilizado o PID, não seria o mesmo para ambiente  Linux ?

Comment: Execute o comando netstat -tlnp, verá a lista de portas abertas

Comment: @BrunoRigolon você não acha que esta pode ser uma resposta em vez de um comentário?

Comment: @FlávioGranato, estava aguardando gerando a imagem para mostrar a saída do comando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute o comando `netstat -tlnp`, veja o resultado:

Temos o protocolo, como TCP/UPD, o IP de escuta e a porta. No final temos o PID e também qual programa está executando.

[image: Saída do comando netstat -tlnp]

Comment: Obrigado era isso que precisa